# Python tuples and sum() inquiry

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

So , I just went on to the tuples section in accordance with Think Python tutorial and what I want to ask is why does this work:

```
def sumall(*args):
    return sum(args)
print sumall(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

and this

```
sum(1,2,3,4)
```

doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `args` is a *tuple*, which is *one* argument. The following does the same as your function and works:

```
sum((1,2,3,4))
```

Without the extra parenthesis, you are calling `sum()` with four separate arguments, so the first argument is not a tuple of 4 integers but just one integer. That doesn't work, because `sum()` expects the first argument to be a sequence instead. An optional second argument can be used to give a different start value (default is 0), which means `sum()` takes at most 2 arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, I can literally feel my brain expanding the last few days, it's like I never had to think before I started learning Python.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference between built-in `sum` and your `sumall`. `sum` receives an iterable (typically `list` or `tuple`) argument (always one argument!) and `sumall` receives as many arguments as you passed.

Why is that? Because you added an asterisk sign in your function signature, built-in sum would be defined like the following:

```
def sum(args): # note: no asterisk here
  result = 0
  for val in args:
    result += val
  return result
```